# Where do a Grails controller's "expando" methods come from?

Tags: grails

According to the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html), a Grails controller is simply a class with "Controller" appended to the name and saved in `grails-app/controllers/`. The simplest of such a class being:

```
package some.package

class FooController {
  def index = {}
}
```

When the Grails application is run, this controller will inherit some standard methods like `getParams` and `getSession`. From the attached screenshot I can see that these are added via `groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass`. What I don't see is how this happens. The controller doesn't implement any interfaces or extend any abstractions. Where do these methods come from?

[image: Controller object graph]

Comment: Adding methods and properties can be done via Groovy runtime and compile time meta-programming. Grails uses those tactics to make the "magic" happen. It modifies all controllers by convention. Are you asking where the actual code is that does it?

Comment: That's like asking where rainbows come from. They're just so awesome, who cares!!

Comment: @JamesKleeh if that's the only answer, yes. I don't like not knowing where to look for an answer when I have a question about something. In this case, where would I look to learn about all of the "inherited" methods available to a controller and what they do? As of now, I have to set a breakpoint, dig through the graph, and then guess.

Comment: @Gregg if no one had bothered to wonder about the origin of rainbows we wouldn't have prisms. And without prisms we wouldn't be having this conversation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Grails 2.0 a new methodology was adapted to add the dynamic methods to the controller artefacts. You can visit them step wise to see how those properties are added to Controllers:-

- Controller in grails is not part of grails-core but a plugin by itself to grails named [grails-plugin-controllers](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/tree/master/grails-plugin-controllers).
- Being a plugin, the corresponding [*GrailsPlugin](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-controllers/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/ControllersGrailsPlugin.groovy) Class would define the behavior of the plugin.
- [ControllersApi](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-controllers/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/api/ControllersApi.java) (extending CommonWebApi) bears all those properties which are to added to controller artefact. (Introduced from Grails 2.0)
- [ControllerGrailsPlugin](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-controllers/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/ControllersGrailsPlugin.groovy) registers ControllersApi as a [spring bean](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-controllers/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/ControllersGrailsPlugin.groovy#L97).
- There is more to just adding ControllerApi as a bean.
- There is a concept of [MetaClassEnhancer](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-core/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/metaclass/MetaClassEnhancer.groovy) which would take/consider an API (in this case ControllerApi) and enhance/reconcile the artefact (controller) with the corresponding API by adding CachedMethods to the artefact using reflection, which is the role of a [BaseApiProvider](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-core/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/metaclass/BaseApiProvider.java) present in grails-core.
- This [magic happens in the Controller plugin class](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-controllers/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/ControllersGrailsPlugin.groovy#L189) as well.

Now, prior to Grails 2.0 a different method was adapted to add the dynamic properties to controller. That way metaClass properties were added to controllers at runtime which was found to be less efficient. Each of the dynamic property was represented by its own class (viz: GetParamsDynamicProperty, GetSessionDynamicProperty) which is not in use right now.

So what you need to look now in the object tree for those dynamic methods is [this](http://pbrd.co/16EDv7A) where the CachedMethods are available in the controller. Hope that helps. I would be glad to add more if you seek more. :-)

Comment: I wouldn't treat it as a mess because the way this plugin is tailored reflects a fine grained approach by using AST transforms and as said earlier MetaClassEnhancer. As an author, one would have full control over the framework while connecting the beads. :-) @jsumners

Answer (score 1):

You are right, Grails 'Controllers' are not really Controllers in the sense they inherit from a base class, but rather they are just simple POGOs that follow the convention of being placed in the `grails-app/controllers` directory.  When your application is compiled, 30+ methods are mixed in through AST transformations, the majority of them coming from

[`org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.api.ControllersApi`](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.3/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/api/ControllersApi.html), but also from 
   [`org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.converters.api.ConvertersControllersApi`](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.3/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/converters/api/ConvertersControllersApi.html),
   [`org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.api.ControllersMimeTypesApi`](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.3/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/api/ControllersMimeTypesApi.html).

The preceding was paraphrased from [Programming Grails](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024750.do) by Burt Beckwith, and I would recommend it if you are interested in the finer details of Grails.

Comment: Thank you for the links to the classes. They help.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from Burt Beckwith's excellent book, [Programming Grails](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024750.do):

> Over 30 methods are mixed into controller classes with AST
>   transformations. The majority are added from the
>   `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.api.ControllersApi` class

[ControllersApi source](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-controllers/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/api/ControllersApi.java)